# Upload multiple .ts files to YouTube as one video?

Tags: java, video, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have a multiple ts files and would like to upload it to YouTube as one video. This basically breaks the question into two parts and would like to know if it's possible.

1. Can multiple individual files be uploaded in a sequence as one video to YouTube through their API?
2. Does YouTube truly supports ts files upload?

Answer (score 1):

**1. Can multiple individual files be uploaded in a sequence as one video to YouTube through their API?**

YouTube is a video upload platform and does not provide any functionality for video editing. Hence, if you'd like to upload these files as one video, you'd have to join these yourself and then upload. However, you could upload these videos as a playlist in your channel. For which, take a look at the [playlist](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists) and [Insert video](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert) section of the YouTube API documentation.

**2. Does YouTube truly supports ts files upload?**

Here is a list of [supported Youtube file formats](https://support.google.com/youtube/troubleshooter/2888402?hl=en). Unfortunately, it doesn't seem like TS is one of them.

Hope this helps.